# the problem when renewing certificate and provisioning

Tags: ios, code-signing

My ios certificate expired.
So I invoked the old certicate and create a new certificate and modify the provisioning of each app(with the same Apple ID).

I downloaded the certificate (distribution_identity.cer) and the app .mobileprovision file and add to 'keychian' and 'Xcode'.

In 'Edit Active Target', I could see 'Code Siging Identity' displaying new provisioning profile, but when I builded the project, it reported errors:

```
CodeSign "build/Ad Hoc-iphoneos/myApp.app"
cd "/Users/myName/iphone source code/myApp All/myApp 1.2"
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv _CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: MYNAME" "--resource-rules=/Users/myName/iphone source code/myApp All/myApp 1.2/build/Ad Hoc-iphoneos/myApp.app/ResourceRules.plist" --entitlements "/Users/myName/iphone source code/myApp All/myApp 1.2/build/myApp.build/Ad Hoc-iphoneos/myApp.build/myApp.xcent" "/Users/myName/iphone source code/myApp All/myApp 1.2/build/Ad Hoc-iphoneos/myApp.app"


iPhone Distribution: MYNAME: ambiguous (matches "iPhone Distribution: MYNAME" in /Users/myname/Library/Keychains/login.keychain and "iPhone Distribution: MYNAME" in /Library/Keychains/System.keychain)
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message seems to tell you what you need to know:

> iPhone Distribution: MYNAME: ambiguous
>   (matches "iPhone Distribution: MYNAME"
>   in
>   /Users/myname/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
>   and "iPhone Distribution: MYNAME" in
>   /Library/Keychains/System.keychain)

You've got two certificates that match the name "iPhone Distribution: MYNAME", and CodeSign doesn't know which one to use.

Comment: yes, I have two "iPhone Distribution: MYNAME"  in 'Keychain Access', I try to remove the old one(expired), but it looks like the removing function does not work. :-(

Comment: even I unlock the keychain, it always has the same result: removing function does not work

Comment: I had to show expired certificates (in view menu) in order to find the one that needed ro be removed. Works for me now.